# Utilizing multiple GPU in my machine (Intel + Nvidia) - Copy data between them

Tags: c++, computer-vision, gpu

My machine has 1 Intel graphic card and 1 Nvidia 1060 card.
I use Nvidia gpu for object detection (Yolo) .

PipeLine
---Stream--->Intel gpu (decode)----> Nvidia Gpu (Yolo)---->Renderer

I want to utilize both of my gpu cards ; I want to use one for decoding frames (Hardware accleration -ffmpeg ) and other for yolo. (Nvidia restricts number of streams that you can decode at one time to 1, but I dont see such restriction with Intel)

Has anyone tried some thing like this ? any pointers on how to do interGPU frame transfer